# Derivative of four-vectors

Tags: special-relativity, kinematics, momentum, differentiation

I have to take the derivative of $(P+2k-2q)^2$ with respect to $k^{\alpha}$. What I am doing is writing

$(P+2k-2q)^2=(P+2k-2q)^{\alpha}(P+2k-2q)_{\alpha}$

Then its derivative comes to be

$2(P+2k-2q)_{\alpha}$

Is this right or do I have consider both cases? For example we can write:

$(P+2k-2q)^2=(P+2k-2q)^{\alpha}(P+2k-2q)_{\alpha}=(P+2k-2q)_{\alpha}(P+2k-2q)^{\alpha}$

So differentiating gives:

$d/dk^{\alpha} (P+2k-2q)^2=d/dk^{\alpha}[(P+2k-2q)^{\alpha}(P+2k-2q)_{\alpha}+(P+2k-2q)_{\alpha}(P+2k- 2q)^{\alpha}]$

Comment: It may help to define P, q, and k.

Comment: This seems to be more of a mathematics problem then a physics one, unless you're able to frame it in a way that it fits here, such as by defining P, q, and k.

Comment: p,q,k are four momentum vectors. These are the calculations of Feynman diagram

Answer (score 1):

You should write

$$(P+2k-2q)^2=(P+2k-2q)^{\beta}(P+2k-2q)^{\gamma}\eta_{\beta\gamma}$$

and use the product rule together with

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial k^{\alpha}}(P+2k-2q)^\beta=2\eta^\beta_\alpha$$